# Map multiple compatible types from a Union type

Tags: typescript

I'm working on an application where we have defined a type and need to deduce multiple interfaces out from that single interface.

Example:

Our main type looks something like this. It is not important if this type is defined as a mapped type or union type, so whatever solution is easiest would be the best.

```
type A = {
  type: "A"
  input: {
    type: "inputA"
  }
  output: {
    type: "outputB"
  }
}

type B = {
  type: "B"
  input: {
    type: "inputB"
  }
  output: {
    type: "outputB"
  }
}

type Definitions = A | B
```

From those definitions, we want to construct a type which encapsulates the function interfaces.

```
type Program<F, K> = F extends { type: K; input: infer I; output: infer O }
  ? (input: I) => O
  : never

type Programs = { [K in Definitions["type"]]: Program<Definitions, K> }

// Correctly deduced type:
// type Programs = {
//     A: (input: {
//         type: "inputA";
//     }) => {
//         type: "outputA";
//     };
//     B: (input: {
//         type: "inputB";
//     }) => {
//         type: "outputB";
//     };
// }
```

We can then provide these functions, something like this:

```
const a = (input: { type: "inputA" }): { type: "outputA" } => {
  return { type: "outputA" }
}

const b = (input: { type: "inputB" }): { type: "outputB" } => {
  return { type: "outputB" }
}

const programs: Programs = {
  A: a,
  B: b,
}
```

So good so far. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to dynamically call these functions. It is important that the `run1` and `run2` functions are typesafe.

```
const run1 = (definition: Definitions) => programs[definition["type"]](definition.input)

// throws error
// Argument of type '{ type: "inputA"; } | { type: "inputB"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
//   The intersection '{ type: "inputA"; } & { type: "inputB"; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
//   Type '{ type: "inputA"; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.

// or 

type Input<F> = F extends { input: infer I } ? I : never
type Output<F> = F extends { output: infer O } ? O : never
type Type<F> = F extends { type: infer T } ? T : never
const run2 = <F>(type: Type<F>, input: Input<F>): Output<F> => {
  return programs[type](input)
}

// yields error
// Type 'Type<F>' cannot be used to index type 'Programs'.
```

Anything I'm missing?

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQTgXjgb1HOlYC44BECBmcAlgHZQCuY+GIWWOM+BlNYxpAvqQPa1O9Us2itCgsJ26M4fEAtAs4AIRTpSLNqpJyOtEXLF5CBsLt4Chhzcezi2UzpbkKl4cXAAiMAGaUZGBk-BQAzhpIAD5qoHEgyl4ACgBO-ADmKQCGALYAPABiADRwANIAfBoFcDAAHmAwFAAmEWgOpqUA3ORUtpR+MClwAJLdzn0UA0MA8vKkAPxwABTm+MMAlCiV06T4FDAAboPxKqkZ2TkRqG0A2qU9Pv6BwaFhNwQsBAC6X-hnmbk8r4AhQgiFwiUKnMEjCAMavMBwLIaFa9OjodoSdho4jydb0TFOGxcAjyLZ2LApGBgagpCgY7SSYm49zxeHhREAIxRqwZjjMaN0eIJjII4wspJ45IYlOptPpbVF4qFrLhCLgUDSAMufy1FyuFMQ+CyRVIqnwnNNijZ6pS1AoAEYUU0nqCXhR8MDnuCwptkJVNedcm8XSCwaF3p8fktQ97QgA6czreInLzDNGFSqoap1BrNVo9YQ9KYjMmLYZwPaHY6eWBwabEzNVGr1RotDHi-D9Qb1su9qtHFKJOsAFXETezLbz7cV-O7QxHfcXA5r7LCiLtFAATBpM0tGWPYJmSrz05xM-j642ClnKjK4FSaXSNXrgzcWF9UZxk9aQEA)

Comment: Could you update the playground link? It shows an almost empty playground with very little code

Comment: @cdimitroulas Yes, done. Sorry about that!

Comment: I think the issue is that `programs[definition["type"]]` returns the union of all the programs, so it's not callable (that's why the compiler error says not assignable to `never`). You can get around this by using a switch statement - see my playground

Comment: Damn, I can't paste the playground link as a comment as it's too long! I've added an answer instead

Comment: Looks like another case of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); you will probably want to just use a type assertion [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2R1N) unless you want redundant code like [@cdimitroulas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67819876/2887218) shows.  There really isn't any great way to do this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that `programs[definition["type"]]` returns the union of all the programs, so it's not callable (that's why the compiler error says not assignable to never).

You can get around this by using a switch statement:

```
const run1 = (definition: Definitions) => {
  switch (definition.type) {
    case "A":
      return programs["A"](definition.input)
    case "B":
      return programs["B"](definition.input)
  }
}
```

You can add an explicit return type to let Typescript warn you if you've missed a case in the switch statement as well:

```
const run1 = (definition: Definitions): Definitions["output"] => {
  switch (definition.type) {
    case "A":
      return programs["A"](definition.input)
    case "B":
      return programs["B"](definition.input)
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKpIC4oCIZ91MBLAOzAFdg9UNMtwI98LrgiSoBfbgexoc63TNhYFBwDlwZ8089OKgAhBMm7jWK4g3Y0RDMc1b7gO7vMxThGo01yShNC3PSK0ygCIQAZhVJgUn5yAGd1OAAfVXQlZigABQAnfgBzJIBDAFsAHgAxAD51PKgIAA9gCHIAE3CkKDM8Cl8IJKgASQBuKBsDBvIWtoB5Xm4AfigACkaOgEoEIqHuPHIIADdW2LQAYxDQ4CgMvGS0zNz6mfqtAjMiXgAaHudaZAcJfF7OfF5eIsRpyg0ebwIr0TBJCDAKhJciva4fZ53eQeXZhA4AI2OKXS2RyF0BLyuJhuBJ0Dye0j6RMcCMp5m%20PF%206gBHGBoO4EKhMLhxNpHDJyK2qP2UDA2LO4UQ9RgeAyjxUeHRozQ6GFBySVHIAEZmdU-AEgiE8D5-ORAsEwmy7JhQgB3QLbAAWUz1pvNIQAdOJ5mDGNsMqFoIR8DhRIxOdDYWLTtlQgBtYMAXUmroNFo9ZlmYf9gYIOlD9nBkMjovFsYTOmTqbNhvIGYJWbcCiAA)

Comment: Relevant issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to call `programs[definition["type"]]` because of contravariance.

Consider this example:

```js
type A = {
  type: "A"
  input: {
    type: "inputA"
  }
  output: {
    type: "outputA"
  }
}

type B = {
  type: "B"
  input: {
    type: "inputB"
  }
  output: {
    type: "outputB"
  }
}

type Definitions = A | B


type Program<F, K> = F extends { type: K; input: infer I; output: infer O }
  ? (input: I) => O
  : never

type Programs = { [K in Definitions["type"]]: Program<Definitions, K> }

const a = (input: { type: "inputA" }): { type: "outputA" } => {
  return { type: "outputA" }
}

const b = (input: { type: "inputB" }): { type: "outputB" } => {
  return { type: "outputB" }
}

const programs: Programs = {
  A: a,
  B: b,
}


const run1 = (definition: Definitions) => {
  const { input } = definition
  const fn = programs[definition["type"]] // expects union of A and B

  if (input.type === 'inputA') {
    fn()
  }
}
```

Because of `fn` arguments are in contravariant position, TS does intersection under the hood. Hence, `{type:'A'} & {type:'B'} === never`

That's why you are unable to call this function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286) you can find a very good answer & explanation

> You want union to intersection? Distributive conditional types and [inference from conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) can do that. (Don't think it's possible to do intersection-to-union though, sorry) Here's the evil magic:

Hence, if you want to make it work, I believe you should stick with **@cdimitroulas** approach.

AFAIK, TS does not play well with nested properties of union type.
But I might be wrong